# How do I fix CORS issue when using Ionicons from CDN?

Tags: cors, ionicons

I have set up a very basic web project with the following files:

- index.html
- styles.css
- scripts.js

I have included the following line in the head of my html file:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I am using the icons like so in my html file:

```
<i class="icon ion-md-menu"></i>
```

The icon was displaying properly but now i am receiving a CORS error when previewing the project.

Access to font at 'https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/fonts/ionicons.woff2?v=4.5.9-1' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Not sure why i am receiving the error now when it was working just fine before.  Any ideas how to fix this issue?  Thanks.

Comment: Try changing the request URL to `https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/fonts/ionicons.woff2` — because that’s the URL `https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/fonts/ionicons.woff2?v=4.5.9-1` redirects to. But the problem is, the 302 redirect response that server sends has an `access-control-allow-origin: https://www.medical-care.net` response header, which means the browser will only follow that redirect if the document making the request is hosted under `https://www.medical-care.net`.

Comment: `https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.2.2/dist/css/ionicons.min.css` was giving me the same issue (had been using that for a year with no issues). Upgrade to `https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.2.6/dist/css/ionicons.min.css` and the issue was resolved.  I guess unpkg are having some config issues?

Comment: Updating the cdn to use `https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.2.6/dist/css/ionicons.min.css` as @Tspoon suggested has the icons displaying properly for me.

Answer (score 2):

it seems to be unpkg issue to inject those url so when I moved to cloudfare cdn that resolve the issue, https://cdnjs.com/libraries/ionicons